# Could disabled products slow down the site?

Tags: magento

I have more and more disabled products and I am wondering if they could slow down my site.

Answer (score 1):

All operations will be much faster on a smaller database. 
Each product has tens of records in the EAV tables. 10-20k inactive products will have a major impact on anything that is not cached. Reindexing will take longer.

You should take into consideration the following when you delete products:

- Reorder will not work (as the same product ordered is expected to exist)
- Check if you have some custom reports/extensions that full the data from the product tables
- Orders/Invoices created already will display all the informations

Comment: hm, none of what you are saying is true and not relevant to his question... either i am missing something here, or nobody care what was asked and what was the answer...

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I really mean the frontand site speed when I am asking this question and not the backend operations. What should be the right answer?

Comment: right answer is: if you had 5k-20k-100k products and you disabled 50% = your site will keep working as before... you just need to keep it OPTIMIZED as usual no matter what. i just on my test setup generated 2K products, and disabled 1K - speed was absolutely the same, before and after... i dont know what this guy FlorinelChis is talking about.

Comment: Actually, @FlorinelChis is right here. He proposes to delete unnecessary products, and this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to optimize the whole thing, and your site was working fine before, deactivating products is not much impact on the speed of the store as a whole.

Comment: A smaller databases behaves better and a larger one. Common sense.

Comment: lol, so you want him to delete all his disabled products??? probably they do as you said, but it`s not a subject...

Comment: ECG (magento's expert consulting group) and industry hosting partners recommend a cleanup for old records that are not used (that includes deleted products). Magento Enterprise has a module for archiving orders (based on the same reason: database becomes too large and it's slow).

Comment: good for them. but if OP will change his question to be more detailed, we will probably answer accordingly. no `reindex`, `database` specific question, but SITE speed.